# Is there a way to add layouts at runtime to an Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create an app to which I can add layouts over time.  E.g. The app ships with a known set of layouts, but can download new theme packs without having to distribute a new apk. I don't expect these to be stored in the layouts directory - they can be stored anywhere the app can access as long as I have a way of loading them.

It looks like layouts need to be compiled into binary form if I'm going to use them with the LayoutInflator. So is there a way to compile them before distribution?  I would really rather not have to write an interpreter for these as I'm sure it would be quite a bit slower.

Comment: You could just create these layouts programmatically.

Comment: XML layout files are pre-processed at compile-time in order to provide optimisation. In other words, a very complex XML layout (if not pre-processed at compile-time) could take a long time to inflate causing problems with delays and UX. In short, no you can't inflate XML files in the way that you want. The docs I read used the word "currently" when explaining this which suggests future versions of Android *may* allow this but obviously that's no guarantee.

Comment: @forgivegod I know I can create them programmatically - that was my comment about having to write an interpreter since the layout.

Comment: @Squonk That's what I was afraid of. It would have been great if they provided a tool to compile the layouts for distribution outside the apk.

Comment: @Ben : Yes, agreed. I can see a reason for what you want to do although I don't have a requirement to do it myself. Unfortunately I don't know of any tool that can do it other than at build time and obviously that means layouts are packaged and only accessible through resource ids during inflation. I suspect it might mean some major changes to the core Android code to be able to use 'external' layout resources.

Answer (score 0):

This layout file in another layout via LayoutInflater.

Suppose, You want to add this layout in your main layout. So, Take a linear layout in main layout and this list layout in main layout via mainlayout.add(view) , Here view is LayoutInflater viw.

Example :

```
private View view;
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_sub_layout,null);
     topicLinearLayout.addView(view); // main Layout Linear layout
```

Thanks.